# Is the visualization_experimental stack still in use?

Tags: rviz, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/visualization_experimental

Is this stack still in use? I want to try the qt rviz stuff on my source based distro and electric, if possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31777/is-the-visualization_experimental-stack-still-in-use?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz_qt is now just rviz!  For Fuerte, it will be the default.  If you build from source, you can easily get it by building fuerte or unstable.

Here's the relevant announcement:
http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20111201.092937.4eb69f25.en.html (was http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/rviz-qt-development-has-merged-back-into-rviz-trunk-td3639336.html)

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-04-13**:
One minor correction: Murph wants to use it with Electric, so the answer there is to keep using the visualization_experimental stack.  However, all development on that tree has ceased, so there are likely many bugs on that branch that will *never* be fixed.